# Content of a inflated EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-context, inflate

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to `getText()` as a readable String from a inflated `EditText`.

I have a boolean method that checks something, so, in the onCreate method i call it like this

```
if(method) {
    if(booleanVariable) {
         LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this);
         View child = factory.inflate(R.layout.password, null);
         mPassword = (EditText)child.findViewById(R.id.password);
           }
}
```

Then thats the part where i try to retrieve the text:

```
private View.OnClickListener btnLoginListener = new View.OnClickListener() {        
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     if(mPassword!=null) {
          if(mPassword.getText().toString()==password) {                    
// LOGIN OK
            } else {
// NOT OK
            }
     }
}
```

Result:

```
07-11 15:39:53.098: VERBOSE/Project(1239): mPassword: <b>android.widget.EditText@43d3ba98</b> password: 329349
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im still quite new and I don't know too much about EditTexts but normally in Java we don't use == for Strings since they are objects.

```
mPassword.getText().toString().equals(password)
```

would be more correct.